# jwPlayer version 5.9 - Need to change only the play icon image

Tags: jwplayer, skin

is there a way to change only 1 specific element of the display component i.e. the playicon image?

If I have to create the whole complete skin just to change this 1 element, can anyone point me to a link where I get and download the Default Skin of jwPlayer 5.9 ?

Also, is there a way to have NO-Background of the display component. I have a transparent playicon image. But a black background is destroying the look of this cool image I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need all of those elements in order to create the play icon.

The JW5 Skin SDK is available here, and it has sample skins - http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/browser/sdks/skinning-sdk?rev=2440

Comment: Hey Ethan...So which one is the default one..beelden or lulu..My customer has asked me to change only the play icon. So I want to make sure all the other things stay as they were..

Comment: The default skin is this one actually - http://www.longtailvideo.com/files/skins/five/5/five.zip